# NGINX default error page

Tags: nginx, errordocument

I'm trying to set a default error_page for my entire nginx server (as in for all vhosts).

I'm trying it with following code:

```
http {
    ...
    ...
    error_page 404 /var/www/default/404.html;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Also, I'd like to be able to create a vhost and make it use the default 404.html if I don't explicitly write another one.

Something like:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name mydomain.com
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/;
    ...
}
```

Anyways, I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] 16842#0: *1 open() "/var/www/mydomain.com/var/www/default/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

While I do understand the error, and I do understand why it's happening, I can't understand why can't I tell NGINX to user the default error_page as an absolute path instead of appending it to the root of my vhost.

Any idea how to make it?

Regards

Comment: `/var/www/default` is not the same as `/var/default/`, did you modify that output by hand at all?

Comment: @gparent Oh, yes, sorry, that's a typo in the error. I'll change it in a second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've already discovered, the `error_page` directive specifies a document that is relative to the document `root`.

One way to work around this is to create a separate file containing your error page specifications, which contains the appropriate `location` blocks, and then `include` that from each `server` which will use the "global" `error_page`.

For example, a file `/etc/nginx/global404`:

```
location = /404.html {
    root /var/www/default;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
```

Now in each `server` block, you will:

```
include global404;
```

Comment: This indeed is a solution, but it's not perfect. Isn't there really some way I could tell NGINX to use a default error_page without having to put it on every server{} ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. This is about the best you can do.

Comment: Do you know if this was asked in the ML of NGINX? If it wasn't, I could try asking and see if they can implement it.

Comment: You can try. Maybe Igor will implement it, or maybe he will yell at you. :)

Comment: Hahaha, let's hope he'll do the first! Or at least won't do the second :P

Comment: @alexandernst Look in `nginx.conf`: if you see the following line in the `http` block:
```include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;```
then you may simply create a file `errors.conf` in `conf.d` and state your error_page directives in there. They will be applied to all of the server configurations in `http`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like error_page is inherited only if there's no other error_page directives in server/location. So to reset error_page 404 for your server, just set some other error page, like:

```
server {
  error_page 399 /;
}
```

This server won't inherit error_page 404 (and any other) from 'html' block.

Answer (score 0):

I plan to use the `include` approach previously submitted but, for the sake of thoroughness, an alternative: Use symlinks. It still requires an extra operation for each vhost you manage but it does offer the benefit of not requiring further server config changes and restarts.

```
http {
    ...
    ...
    error_page 404 /error/404.html;
    ...
    ...
}
```

...and then in each vhost's root...

```
ln -s [path to error page html directory] /[vhost root]/error
```

This approach strikes me as inelegant and unportable (I'd vote it down if I have enough rep to vote things up or down) but it works.